# PhoneGap application with remote java scripts

Tags: cordova

I'm planning to write mobile application using PhoneGap.

My question is: Should Java scripts (with business logic) be packed into distribution package. I need it to avoid resubmitting application to App Store if business logic was updated.

So in the main html were I include PhoneGap JS can I include remote JS?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.0.9.5.1.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://remote.server.com/main.js" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're fine. A few years ago Apple rejected a phonegap application of mine because it retrieved external javascript. It *is* a major security concern for them, but they overlook it now. An app I submitted two weeks ago was accepted with external javascript. The issue lies with the fact that flaws in apple's javascript engine allow it to, if it is written correctly, perform arbitrary code on the device. It is [still](http://www.phonesreview.co.uk/2011/06/12/jailbreakme-pdf-sign-surely-suggest-unlock-ipad-2/) an issue, even with iOS 5 and iPad 2s.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this works fine.  I use Google Maps within a Phonegap application on both iPhone and Android and it works perfectly.